# How to randomize image pattern in Swift? Keep pattern + increase

Tags: ios, swift

New to programming and trying to make my first game. It's 4 UIImages that I want to "turn on" in a pattern as the user copies the pattern. From there is follows that **same** pattern and increases the random pattern. Is arc4random.uniform() what I am looking for here? I know that generates a random number but I'm stuck on how to get the random image to repeat and add +1 random to it.

Comment: you want the range of the random to be 1 higher each time?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 4 images, I'm guessing you want a random number between 1 and 4 to represent the images you want to "turn on". The following can generate a random sequence of images for you (you can test this out in a Swift Playground):

```
import Foundation

let numberOfImages = 4

func addRandom(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var returnArray = array
    returnArray.append(Int(arc4random()) % numberOfImages)
    return returnArray
}

func makePattern(length: Int) -> [Int] {
    var pattern = [Int]()
    for _ in 0...(length - 1) {
        pattern = addRandom(pattern)
    }
    return pattern
}

// Array of 3 random digits
var firstPattern = makePattern(3)

// Same array as before, with one more random digit at the end
var nextPattern = addRandom(firstPattern)

// Same array as before, with yet another random digit at the end
var lastPattern = addRandom(nextPattern)
```

Just for fun, you can do this even more cleanly with a Pattern class, like so:

```
import Foundation

class Pattern {

    private(set) var maxRandomNumber: Int!
    private(set) var pattern: [Int] = [Int]()

    init(maxRandomNumber: Int) {
        self.maxRandomNumber = maxRandomNumber
    }

    init(length: Int, maxRandomNumber: Int) {
        self.maxRandomNumber = maxRandomNumber
        for _ in 0...(length - 1) {
            self.appendRandom()
        }
    }

    func appendRandom() {
        self.pattern.append(Int(arc4random()) % self.maxRandomNumber)
    }
}

// Initialize a new pattern with 3 iterations and a max random number of 4
var pattern = Pattern(length: 3, maxRandomNumber: 4)

// See the pattern
print(pattern.pattern)

// Add another random number on to the end and check
pattern.appendRandom()
print(pattern.pattern)
```

Comment: Thanks Carter I will give this a shot! Yes I do have 4 images and I want them to turn on. Like the old Simon game!

Comment: I was going to ask if it was like Simon! I just wasn't sure if everyone would know what that was though.

Comment: Hey Carter. So I've been looking over the first solution you posted. Been reading up on some of the thing I don't understand in that code (like the for _ in). It's some what helping. However I'm still a little confused. First question is adding my imageviews to this code. Would I be replacing constant "numberOfImages" with a string and if so I'm guessing I need to adjust the "addRandom" method since it's using a Int instead of a String? Very new to this so try to wrap my head around it.

Comment: If your 4 images don't change, you can just store them all in an array like: `let imgArray = [image1, image2, image3, image4]`. Then, without changing the code, just generate a random pattern, say `let pattern = [1,3,0]`. When you light up your images one by one, you just read through the array! So first we do `pattern[0]` which gives `1`, so we light up `imgArray[1]`. Then we do `pattern[1]` which gives `3`, so we light up `imgArray[3]`. And so on.

Comment: Is the array replacing "let numberOfImages = 4" in your example above?

Comment: No, `numberOfImages` should equal how many images you are displaying to the user (4 in a classic game of Simon). More correctly, `numberOfImages` should equal `imgArray.count`.

Comment: I'm stuck still. Guess I'm just not getting it. No matter what I try I get errors when I try to add an array for the images to be used. Is there a good beginners book you would suggest? Maybe I need to start from square one again. Few years ago I started on a C# and Java book but never kept up with it. I really want to get past this hump.

Comment: [This website](https://www.raywenderlich.com) has a ton of good tutorials to get you started! Also, if you like you can email me a link to your github or specific code and I can help out a bit (just check my profile for my website and you'll find my email).